# Hiding An unhandled error has occurred. in production environment

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

When an error occurred runtime the following message is displayed at the bottom of the page

> An unhandled error has occurred.

I know the id of the element is `blazor-error-ui`.

I want to display this error only in the development environment.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this goal, you can use `ErrorBoundary`in the MainLayout.razor as follows:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <ErrorBoundary>
            @Body
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case, any unhandled exception that occurs in the entire program is controlled by `ErrorBoundary` and an error is shown on the page. By default, the `ErrorBoundary` component shows an empty div with a css class in site.css called `blazor-error-boundary` as the error page, which can be customized (In your case, the message section can be left blank).

```
<ErrorBoundary>
    <ChildContent>
        @Body
    </ChildContent>
    <ErrorContent>
        <p class="errorUI">@*blank*@</p>
    </ErrorContent>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Now, in order to take the component to the state before the exception, it is enough to use the `Recover` method as follows:

```
...

<ErrorBoundary @ref="errorBoundary">
    @Body
</ErrorBoundary>

...

@code {
    private ErrorBoundary? errorBoundary;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        errorBoundary?.Recover();
    }
}
```